# Bootstrap collapse js file giving error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following test code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ti Productions</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

    <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>

    <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
    <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

    <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->

              <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="">home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">about</a></li>
              <li><a href="">help</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I'm basically trying to test out the collapsable menu shown here:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

I've downloaded the boostrap responsive css file as per the instructions, and also the collapse.js file. 
The page loads file, with the menu showing.  Then when I shrink the browser size, the menu collapses..and the button appears.  But I can't open the menu.  Whenever i click on the button to display the collapsed menu, I get the following error:

```
--
[19:08:40.348] TypeError: $ is undefined @
https://myserver/mysite/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js:126
```

line 126 of that file looks like this:

```
  $.fn.collapse = function (option) {
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any guesstions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I've added in the missing jquery.js file but that hasn't resolved the issue. 
The includes at the bottom of the page now looks like this:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you include the files in correct order i.e. bootstrap.js then responsive and then collapse.js?

Comment: baig772. thanks for the comment.  yes, i've added in the same order you mentioned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is a jQuery function and needs to be included before the bootstrap-collapse.js.

Try this sequence

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
```

Comment: Kane, I've tried that but it still isn't working.  check out "edit 1" in my post.  thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your assets are in a sub folder called assets? Could it be a simple fix of adding a leading slash `/assets`?

Answer (score 1):

check if jquery is properly loaded or not . IN Firebug or console try running "$". This type of errors comes , if jquery is not loaded before custom script or their is a conflict with other library using '$' like prototype.